# Use of possessive apostrophe with "every"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

In the following sentence, can anyone tell me where the apostrophe should be placed please?

- Every coders' worst nightmare
- Every coder's worst nightmare

I have a feeling that the second sentence is correct - i.e. "every" should be followed by a singular noun, but I would welcome any confirmation.
thanks

Comment: Thanks both. That really helps. I have marked the first reply as the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Every" in this context implies a singular noun follows, so "coder's" works here. It's a nightmare that is personal to every individual in the set of coders.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second one is correct.

If you think of it like this, it may help to understand why:

> Every single coder's worst nightmare.