# Every Soldiers Lament

Tags: possessives

I wrote a poem called "Every Soldiers Lament"
and am torn with the spelling of Soldiers.

Is it:

1. Soldiers
2. Soldier's
3. Soldiers'

My first guess is "Soldiers'" because I'm referring to all soldiers.

But "Soldiers" seems appropriate because all soldiers are included.

I know it's not "Soldier's" because that means only one soldier.

The question is:  what is the correct spelling for this example?

Comment: This is essentially the same question, excluding the poetic aspect: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208185/use-of-possessive-apostrophe-with-every?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Every Soldier's Lament" is correct.
Yes, you're referring to all soldiers, but the word "every" makes that clear. I'm not sure the linguistic *reason* but "every" almost always uses a singular noun. Essentially the lament comes from (or belongs to) each individual one out of the set of all soldiers.

"Soldiers' Lament" would also be correct but would not emphasize as strongly the idea that all the soldiers have the same lament.

"Soldiers Lament" would also be correct but have a different meaning - more like a statement that some soldiers do some lamenting, rather than a title indicating I'm about to read the actual lament.

Of course in a poem (including its title), it's not necessary to adhere to strict rules, or any rules. You can spell it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is offered not to disagree with the answer given by @solublefish, which is about how to use **every** and is correct. But I will suggest alternatives to **every**.

You can call the poem *A Soldier's Lament* or *The Soldier's Lament*.

If you call it *A Soldier's Lament* you are leaving it up to the audience to decide if it applies universally to all soldiers but not implying that it does. If you call it *The Soldier's Lament*, it is ambiguous whether you are implying that it is universal, since universality--genericity--is one of the ways the definite article can be understood.

Comment: I agree these could be solid options depending on the poet's intent. (Not my downvote)

Comment: Thank you solublefish. TimR, I like your two examples of titles but the poem is about all soldiers. Maybe if you read my poem it will help. It's posted at www.Facebook.com/RP.Infantino or if I'm allowed I'll paste it right here.

Apologies if I'm not allowed to post a website link, but I believe reading the poem would help with this question. Even though the poem only has two soldiers debating, they represent all soldiers.

Comment: @R.P.  I liked the  poem about the fall of Icarus and the angle suggested by your title.

Comment: Thank you, TimR. 

All accounts of "The Fall of Icarus" mention the son. I've always felt that Daedalus was the more important in the story. What a gifted genius he was.  The son was just an irresponsible boy, same as the one in The Parable of the Lost Son. I felt that HIS father was the greater man as well.

Imagine being a parent and losing a child, no matter how irresponsible that child is.